# Convert editText number input to percentage in real time not working in real device

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to convert the input of an editText to percentage while the user input it, the following code is not working, on the real device. It does format correctly on emulator.

```
public class PercentTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private final EditText percentage;
private final Locale locale;


public PercentTextWatcher(EditText percentage, Locale locale) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
    this.locale = locale;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    percentage.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    if (percentage == null) return;
    percentage.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(locale);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    String percentNumber = format.format(convertToDouble(percentage.getText().toString())/1000);

    percentage.setText(percentNumber);
    percentage.setSelection(percentNumber.length()-1);
    percentage.addTextChangedListener(this);

}

private double convertToDouble(String value) {
    double convertedNumber = 0;
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##,##");
    try {
        convertedNumber = nf.parse(value).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedNumber;
}
```

The keyboard does not accept anymore input after the first char, and returns 0,001% for example.

Comment: where do you have spannablestringbuilder? the exception tells you that you setSpan to a part of string that is more than the actual length. That's why IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I do not have it

Comment: Fixed it, had to remove android:maxLength=" " from XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem is you try to access some index that is not present that's why `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I believe there could be 2 places

**1.** You're using

`percentage.setSelection(formatted.length());`

and the indices start with `0`. So please, try

`percentage.setSelection(formatted.length()-1);`

**2.** There could be that you're setting text into a `textview` that is longer than the allowed length of your input in the `textview`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi Rainmaker I did try it, but no sucess. My previous code was working on emulator and not on the real device.

Comment: so did you overcome IndexOutOfBoundsException then ? but it doesn't perform as expected?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks ! Now just the conversion that is messed up. Working on that